# I can't see a nearby notification in association with a beacon

Tags: android, google-nearby

My device got yesterday the update of the google services app.

I have tested the [google nearby notifications](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview) on Android with two beacons, one iBeacon and one Eddystone-UID.

These beacons are active, and are correctly registered in the platform.
(I see them as registred in the Android Beacon Tool app).

I added to them an url nearby notification attachment from the Google Beacons Dashboard.

My device does not receive any notifications in relation with these beacons
while my device correctly receives the one from a physical web beacon (emitting an Eddystone-url) with the new nearby notification system (not the Chrome one)

Is the nearby notification ready with iBeacon and Eddystone-UID ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Android users will stop receiving Nearby Notifications on December 6th, 2018.  Deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem seems to be a language management bug in the google proximity platform.

My mobile is in french. 
I added an attachement with as language "fr". I can't get it.

If I put an attachement with as language "en", I can see it on my phone in the "nearby discoveries" page (while my phone is in french)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the nearby notification is ready with eddystone UID.

The process is:

1. Get eddystone supported beacons
2. Configure your beacons to a namespace ID and an instance ID(usually this is done with the help of an app which is provided by the device manufacturer)
3. Register your eddystone UID beacon with the help of beacon tools app. (Make sure you have created a project before doing so)
4. Once the beacon(eddystone UID is registered), open Google beacon dashboard.
5. Select the registered device, toward top left, you will find a drop down, select nearby notification from  there.
6. Fill the appropriate fields. Try to create multiple notifications using different URL's like facebook.com, Google.com etc.
7. Now bring your beacon near your android phone, switch on bluetooth and location.
8. You should see a notification which reads as "website for this location found""

   ---

If still after following the above process, you cannot find the notification.
Go to you Google settings from the apps drawer and see if you can find an option called nearby discoveries.

If nearby discoveries is present that would mean your play services is updated to 9.2.55 and nearby notifications should work.

Also, do let me know your Android phone model.

Thank You

Comment: My Eddystone UUID beacon is correctly configured : I saw it in the list of registered beacons in your beacon tools application with the various nearby attachments I configured. All the urls are in https.                                                                                                         In the "nearby discoveries", I see the Eddystone-URL beacon, but I can't see that nearby attachments I have configured on my Eddyston-UUID beacon.                                                                                                     My mobile is a nexus 5X.